# Running a SQL query in excel usin VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that pulls data from a user-chosen workbook.
What I need is: 1) prompt user to choose which file they want to use 2) [Assuming a "Data" sheet always exists and has the same format] select * from Data worksheet where a condition is met 3) Output this in my excel file

My code is

```
Sub ConnectionToExcel()
Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnectin As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strSQL As String

strPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
strConnectin = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & strPath & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=0"" "
Debug.Print strConnectin

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$] "

Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
rstResult.Open strSQL, strConnectin
'adOpenForwardOnly , adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

Sheets("Export").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rstResult

End Sub
```

I am not sure how to add the condition in the select statement. The condition would be to select the items based on a given value in one of the cols. So for example, Select * from table where Product=Banana"

```
ID  Product
14243   Apple
43543   Banana
43432   Banana
```

Thanks

I tried a couple of if statements,

```
if worksheets(Data).range("A1:A220000")="Condition" then
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$] "
end if
```

I also tried adding a where clause in the select statement but doesn't seem to work either

Comment: You will need a where-clause. The simple (but dirty) method is `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$]  where [Product] = '" & Condition & "'"` (you have to set the search term into single quote). The cleaner method is to work with ADODB.Command and ADODB.Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using Data$.Product='Banana' as WHERE clause.

```
Sub ConnectionToExcel()
  Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim strConnectin As String
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strSQL As String

  strPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
  
  strConnectin = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & strPath & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=0"" "
  Debug.Print strConnectin

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$] WHERE (Data$.Product='Banana')"

  Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
  rstResult.Open strSQL, strConnectin
  'adOpenForwardOnly , adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

  Sheets("Export").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rstResult

End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to use the range function in the where clause? For example,   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Data$] WHERE (Data$.Range("A1:A200000")='Banana')"

Comment: Tested not possible, as SQL query has no notion of range, but table.column/field system.